# Impermissible cast of composite expression (wider essential type for the destination) stack overflow

Tags: c, pointers, misra

Pseudo code -

```
void a(Atype *b)
{
  uint32 i = 0;
  uint32 b;
  b = (uint32)(&b[i]);
}
```

For the line in code -  b = (uint32)(&b[i]);
i get warning as
Impermissible cast of composite expression (wider essential
type for the destination) [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.8, required].

I am not able to understand the warning. Any help?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Daoes that even compile? And don't cast a pointer to other than `(u)intptr_t`

Comment: "Pseudo code" does not generate warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You are shadowing the variable `b` passed as a parameter, so `Atype` is not relevant.

Then you are attempting to access `b[i]` where `b` is a `uint32`. That is not meaningful: `b` is not a pointer or array type.

Your program behaviour is undefined. I'm amazed this compiled.

Comment: Hmm, both have the same scope, so it should not even compile.